# Tinymce and cookie management

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I have a website using tinymce 4 (yes it's an old version but I can not upgrade :(). In order to manage cookies, I have implemented the tarteaucitron.io solution. In tinymce, editors can add Vimeo. In order to manage vimeo cookie, instead of adding the code:

```
  <iframe width="width" height="height" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/video_id" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You have to use:

```
   <div class="vimeo_player" videoID="video_id" width="width" height="height"></div>
```

I have so create a plugin asking for the 3 needed parameters and insert the content in tinymce. This does work but I would like to reproduce what does the media plugin:

- the inserted content is not editable (the content has been replaced by an image in the tinymce)
- when selecting the inserted content, you can edit/update it

Any idea on how to do that?